# How to style multiple variations of a <button> with Styled Components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, css-modules

I have a simple colored button in my app that needs to change color based on some UI state:

```
const StyledButton = styled.button`
  & {
    border: 0;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  &:hover {
    background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.hoverColor};
  }
  &.base {
    background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.baseColor};
  }
  &.selected {
    background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.selectedColor};
  }
  &&.danger:hover {
    background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.dangerColor};
  }
  &.disabled {
    background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.disabledColor};
  }
`;
```

Previously I was using [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) to make sure classes would not "leak" to other styles and I have obtained the styled component by essentially a 1-to-1 translation.

```
.Button {
  border: 0;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Button:hover {
  background-color: var(--hover-color);
}
.Button.base {
  background-color: var(--base-color);
}
.Button.selected {
  background-color: var(--selected-color);
}
.Button.Button.danger:hover {
  background-color: var(--danger-color);
}
.Button.disabled {
  background-color: var(--disabled-color);
}
```

I like the theming support in Styled Components, but I dislike how now my "local" classes are no longer local to the component. I consider this a significant tradeoff.

Am I missing the correct way of implementing multiple variants of a component?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I have found two solutions:

The first is to calculate by hand the end result and avoid any classes

```
const StyledButton = styled.button`
  & {
    border: 0;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  ${(props) =>
    props.isBase &&
    css`
      &,
      &:hover {
        background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.baseColor};
      }
    `}
  ${(props) =>
    props.selectedColor &&
    css`
      &,
      &:hover {
        background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.selectedColor};
      }
    `} 
  ${(props) =>
    props.isDisabled &&
    css`
      &,
      &:hover {
        background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.disabledColor};
      }
    `}
  ${(props) =>
    props.isDanger &&
    css`
      & {
        background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.dangerColor};
      }
      &:hover {
        background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.dangerColor};
      }
    `}
`;
```

which works but is quite ugly

and the other is to split the StyledButton into many components:

```
const StyledButton = styled.button`
  & {
    border: 0;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.baseColor};
  }
`;
const StyledSelectedButton = styled(StyledButton)`
  & {
    background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.selectedColor};
  }
`;

const StyledDisabledButton = styled(StyledButton)`
  & {
    background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.disabledColor};
  }
`;

const StyledDangerButton = styled(StyledButton)`
  & {
    background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.baseColorColor};
  }
  &&:hover {
    background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.dangerColor};
  }
`;
```

Which is better but I am afraid of an eventual combinatorial explosion once more complex states are involved (a selected danger component) or more pseudoclasses are involved.

Moreover if the button in question had a state (e.g. a click counter) changing style would destroy the state.

I cannot think of a solution around this problem.